# How can I get Table of Contents to fill the page?

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

If the Table of Contents has only a few lines, how can I add spaces between the lines so that it fills the whole page? Is there a command similar to `\vfill` ?

Comment: I strongly suggest let LaTeX do its best and decide this for you.  Forcing this type of things usually don't have a good result.

Comment: Do you have to follow a style guide? I haven't seen a single ToC that was vertically spread to fill the (last) page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each entry in the table of contents is set as separate paragraph. Therefore the distance between entries can be set via `\parskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \flushbottom
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1fil}%
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
\endgroup
\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\subsection{Subsection C}
\section{Section D}
\subsection{Subsection E}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

```
{\setlength\parskip{\fill}
\tableofcontents

}
```

Probably works but the affect might be a bit odd....